# Need async http client(NIO) which supports http/socks proxy

Tags: java, http, proxy, client, nio

I seek some full featured async http client (using NIO, not thread per connection), that supports connections through all kinds of proxy(http/https/socks4/socks5).
I need different proxy per connection, not one global proxy for all connections.
so... what library i can use?

P.S. sorry for my english

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Solution found!
look at http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this: https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client